# rsnapshot ignoring a "backup" line, logs are empty

Tags: debian, backup, rsnapshot

I've been using `rsnapshot` to backup my server. In one server (debian 7) the exact same config works as expected. In the other (debian 8), it skips a directory im trying to backup, which has mysql dump files.

Tried changing it's order. Tried commenting all the other ones. Made the log level 5 (debug), still it ignores that directory for some reason. The dir is a regular dir, no link, no network share. `rsnapshot` is backing up in to a CIFS drive, on a storage server.

This is the backup part of the config.

```
# LOCALHOST
backup  /home/                  localhost/
backup  /etc/                   localhost/
backup  /usr/local/             localhost/
backup  /var/www/html/          localhost/
backup  /var/mysql_backup/      localhost/
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You sure the folder is name directly and there aren't any typos in the config or the folder name?

Comment: Yes, I always copy-paste it to avoid confusions.

Comment: I just copied the command from rsnapshot -t daily, and it runs fine. Just not in the cron. That is weird.

Comment: Well, seems rsnapshot is skipping a lot of stuff, or just not making the hardlinks. And the logs are non helpful. I'm giving up on it, tying BackupPC / rdiff-backup

Comment: Are you using spaces or tabs, IIRC rsnapshot configs require tab demarcation between directives and values.

Comment: I have given up on rsnapshot. Though I did use the right format, the rsnapshot didn't run when there were syntax errors in the the code